# PHP How to use old image if no image selected

Tags: php, file-upload, if-statement, image-uploading

How is it possible to use old image if no image is selected?

its a profile page when someone updates his profile but don't select the image for update then old image should be remained there..

should it be like this if-else statement or there would be some other way??

```
    //check if file is selected.
    if (empty($_FILES['profilepic']))
    {
                 //if file selected this code should run

         $fileselected="file selected";
    }
    else
    {
                //this executes if file not selected
        $fileselected="No File Has Been Selected";
    }

echo $fileselected;
```

How it should be coded??

Comment: `if($_FILES["profilepic"]["error"]){//if the file is not selected} else {//if the file is selected}`. Use different SQL statements based on this condition (depending upon your requirements).

Comment: what is your update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Lion

```
if($_FILES["profilepic"]["error"])
{//if the file is not selected} 
else {//if the file is selected}
```

Pretty much works for me.. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Mark your answer as an accepted answer (when the system permits).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
{
    $image=$row['image'];
    //upload from root folder//
    $upload=$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadURL'] = '/images'.$image;
    upload script
} else {
    normal upload script
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.